Is there a way to make a multi-colored matplotlib legend line?

I have a time series that I am coloring by the values of the x-axis using a line collection that gets plotted as a line plot and scatter plot to indicate discrete time step sampling. I would like the legend line with marker (emulating the line/scatter) to be similarly multi-colored.
I have made a legend line using Line2D with a marker style to emulate the line and scatter in the main plot. It only allows a single color though.
These answers 1 2 to a related question could be relevant.
MRE:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib import cm

# Generate some data
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(x)

# Pick colormap and make continuous cmap discrete for evolving outlines
colormap = 'plasma'
continuous_cmap = matplotlib.colormaps[colormap]
discrete_cmap = colors.ListedColormap(continuous_cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))))

# Normalize the data for the colormap
norm = Normalize(vmin=x.min(), vmax=x.max())

# Create the points in pairs to form line segments
points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

# Create the LineCollection object
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap=discrete_cmap, norm=norm, linestyle='dotted')
# Set the array used for coloring to x
lc.set_array(x)

# Create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.autoscale()

# Scatter plot, using the discrete colormap and norm for coloring
scatter = ax.scatter(x, y, c=x, cmap=discrete_cmap, norm=norm)

# Include a colorbar
plt.colorbar(lc, ax=ax, label='Value of x')

# Add labels and title
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

# Creating a legend with both line and scatter
legend_line_and_scatter = Line2D([0], [0], linestyle='dotted', color='blue', marker='.', markersize=10, label='Line and Scatter')
ax.legend(handles=[legend_line_and_scatter])

plt.show()

